How can I print without rendering it using react-to-print?
Is it possible to use react-to-print without rendering the details to the ui? What i'm trying to do is create a print button without rendering the other details coming from child component.
ParentComponent.tsx
return (
   <FormToPrint form={form} />
)

ChildComponent.tsx
interface FinalizeFormProps {
  form: UseFormReturn<any>; // Replace 'any' with your specific form data type
}


const FormToPrint = ({ form }: FinalizeFormProps) => {
  const contentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const reactToPrintFn = useReactToPrint({
    contentRef
  });



  return (
    <>
      <div ref={contentRef} >
      <p className="text-sm font-bold">Print this but don't show to the UI</p>

      </div>
      <Button type="button"
        className="mb-5"
        //@ts-ignore
        onClick={reactToPrintFn}>
        Print Form
      </Button>
    </>
  )
}

export default FormToPrint

Currently this is what happens. It shows the UI


but when I add a hidden the className. It disappear which is not what I want.

Are you aware of the CSS "media" feature which can be used to style only while printing? There are examples of use in the react-to-print documentation

You could try adding a wrapping div, and make that hidden instead. This way when you print the component/node of interest, it does not get hidden as the styles you apply on the component to print style your print-out.
For example (also see Package documentation);
<div className="hidden">
    <div ref={contentRef} >
        <p className="text-sm font-bold">
            Print this but don't show to the UI
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

